# How to remove quotation marks from InputString?

Tags: input

I want to make a script for solving liniar equations (in Mathematica) with something like:

```
Solve[{InputString["Solving Linear Equations"]}]
```

The output is similar to:

```
Solve[{"x+y+z==0,x+y+z==0,x+y+z==0"}]
```

I want to remove the quotation marks. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try this: `Solve[ImportString["{" <> InputString["Solve Equations:"] <> "}", "Package"], {x, y, z}]`.

Comment: It's a good idea to look at the related functions in the documentation, in particular `Input` (and the tutorial).

Comment: @J.M. Doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is very vague and does not give me much to diagnose. What did you input, what error messages did you get, what did the result (in `InputForm[]`) look like... now those would be more helpful information to have.

Comment: I've entered x+y+z==0 three times. 
The error message is
 Solve::naqs: x+y+zï\:f290\[PlusMinus]0&&x+y+zï\:f290\[PlusMinus]0&&x+y+zï\:f290\[PlusMinus]0 is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. 

(https://imgur.com/VMOt2qk)

Comment: Something's weird with your setup, if it's suddenly inserting `\[PlusMinus]` at weird places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solve[ToExpression@
  StringSplit[InputString["Solving Linear Equations"], ","]]
```

Paste in `x+y+z==0,x+y+z==0,x+y+z==0`

> {{z -> -x - y}}

Comment: Always be wary of using `ToExpression` blindly.  For your code, a user could enter something like `Print["deleting files"], DeleteFile /@ FileNames["*"]` at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here is a way to do it with `AskFunction`.

```
solver =
  AskFunction[
    Solve[Ask["equations" -> "Expression"], Ask["variables" -> "Expression"]]];

solver[]
```

[image: input1]

[image: input2]

> `{{x -> 2/3, y -> 1/3}}`

Note: This has the advantage that you don't have to convert strings to expressions and the disadvantage requiring an internet connection to convert the textual inputs into Mathematica expressions.